# Data Usage Service usage and functionality

Tags: windows-10, services

I was going through services to disable and I stumbled upon Data Usage service.

The description says:

> Data Usage
>
> > Network data usage, data limit, restrict background data, metered networks.

so I disabled it since I don't care for any of it.
My question is: Does this service do only that what's in the description or is there some "hidden" useful functionality behind it?

Comment: Your question doesn't match with the heading. Edit that. Question is too broad. That service is depend on `"C:\Windows\System32\dusmsvc.dll"` file. No user can easily know all details of a DLL file without source code.

Comment: That service is new following the release of Windows 10 version 1703 back in March 2017.  However, you really should proceed with *extreme* caution before changing the default status of Windows services.  There are some excellent resources available online that can help teach us much more about Windows services configuration and optimization, such as [Black Viper’s Windows 10 Service Configurations](http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-10-service-configurations/)

Answer (score 1):

This service is useful if you want to limit network usage by background processes. This can be done by setting (`Windows 10 -> Settings -> Network and Internet -> Data Usage -> Background Data Transfer: Limit = Always`). In my opinion, this could be useful, for example, for online games. However, this can also affect the speed of background downloads.